# C++ library python binding generation with Shiboken

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyside, python-bindings

I followed the tutorial up on the wiki http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide_Binding_Generation_Tutorial
but I can't get it to work properly. I'm on MacOSX

So far here's what I did:

- Build FooLib (static) ---> libFooLib.a
- Create the typesystem_foo.xml
- Run shiboken with the following command:

  shiboken-2.7 global.h --include-paths=.:/opt/local/include/PySide-2.7:/opt/local/include --typesystem-paths=/opt/local/share/PySide-2.7/typesystems --output-directory=../FooLibBinding typesystem_foo.xml
- Build the FooLibBinding dynamic library from the resulted generated c++ code --> libFooLibBinding.dylib

Now instead of just running python interpreter from the command line, I made a C++ program which would load the python interpreter and open a .py script using the FooLib. This program links dynamically against   libFooLibBinding.dylib so I guess all the symbols needed for the foolib module to work are there;)

here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    ///Python init
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PySys_SetArgv(argc, argv); /// relative module import

    ///Try out loading the module, this is just for testing
    /// -----------
    PyObject *sysPath = PySys_GetObject("path");
    PyObject *path = PyString_FromString("/Users/alexandre/Downloads/BindingTest");
    int result = PyList_Insert(sysPath, 0, path);
    PyObject *pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("foolib");
    if (PyErr_Occurred())
            PyErr_Print();
    /// -----------

    ///Our python file to interpret
    const char* filename = "/Users/alexandre/Downloads/BindingTest/FooLibTest/foolib_test.py";
    FILE* file = fopen(filename,"r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(file,filename);

    ///close python
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

When running the program, it fails when trying to load the module a first time saying:
    ImportError: No module named foolib

And then a second time when running the .py script :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexandre/Downloads/BindingTest/FooLibTest/foolib_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foolib import FooClass
ImportError: No module named foolib
```

So obviously it cannot find the module generated from the bindings. My question is what should I do so it can find it ?

The tutorial uses a Makefile but doesn't seem to do much more than just linking the binding dynamic library.

Answer (score 0):

Your include path for the Shiboken command line doesn't include the path to your foo.h. I can't tell if this is the cause of your problem, but if I did the same, it won't generate the following files:

- math_wrapper.cpp
- math_wrapper.h

...which you'd obviously need to be able to compile support for the Maths class in the foo library.